# Spring Boot test fails in Maven, works in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have made a Spring Boot test for testing JMS consumption.

The test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class UpdateThingByJmsIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void updateThingByJmsUpdatesDatabase() throws InterruptedException {
        final Thing thing = new ThingBuilder().withId(null).build();

        final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> {
            thingRepository.save(thing);
            return thing;
        });

        final String xml = String.format(
                "<thingDto><id>%s</id><name>something else</name><location>somewhere</location></thingDto>",
                thing.getId());

        jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(thingUpdateQueue, xml);

        Thread.sleep(1500L);

        final Thing updatedThing = thingRepository.getOne(thing.getId());

        assertNotNull(updatedThing);
        assertEquals("something else", updatedThing.getName());
        assertEquals("somewhere", updatedThing.getLocation());
    }
```

So, I save a `Thing` in the database, then send a JMS message to update the `Thing`. Since JMS consumption happens in a separate thread from the test itself, I wait, and then try to verify that the `Thing` has been updated.

This works just fine in IntelliJ, but when running it with Maven it fails, due to the thread consuming the JMS message not being able to find the `Thing` in the database.

I have tried to output the object hashcode (identifier) of the `ThingRepository` in both the test and the code consuming the JMS message, and they come out differently. With IntelliJ they are the same. I suspect this might be part of the problem, but I'm not sure how to avoid it.

I also checked the log output in IntelliJ vs Maven, and I find that maven outputs these lines before the test is even run, which IntelliJ does not. Don't know if it is relevant.

```
2019-05-13 09:48:53.983  INFO 9271 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-13 09:48:53.995  INFO 9271 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-05-13 09:48:53.996  INFO 9271 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2019-05-13 09:48:54.000  INFO 9271 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-05-13 09:48:54.001  INFO 9271 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown completed.
```

But why would I get a different repository-object in the test and the class under test?

Update:

Turns out this only happens when running the test in question in the same run as another test. In this other test, I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class OtherIntegrationTest {
    @MockBean
    private ThingRepository thingRepository;
```

It seems this "bleeds" through to my other test, making the context use a mock while my test uses the real deal. Any way to avoid this, or do I have to find an alternative to using @MockBean?

Comment: How are your running the test Maven? As a single test `mvn test -Dtest=` or as part of build with other tests? Maybe it's the isolation between tests which is failing?

Comment: I'm running mvn clean install. I'll try to run it as a single test.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki It works if I'm running it as a single test through maven. I also see that I'm getting the same object hashcode in the test and class under test in this scenario. All tests that are run as Spring boot tests are annotated with DirtiesContext BEFORE_EACH_METHOD.

Comment: I tried to run it along with another test class with no failing tests, and it works. Then, I tried along with another test class, which has a failing test, and it does not work. So it may seem that the error is caused by the other test, I'll investigate that a bit further

Comment: Running single tests was good advice, thanks :)

Comment: How's "running single tests" a valid and accepted answer here?

Comment: @GabrielOshiro It helped me along to solve my issue, and I don't see any other answers, so.

Comment: @Tobb hehehehe I see, well if you ever have more information and you can add your own answer that would be very helpful and appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by lack of proper test isolation. If the `updateThingByJmsUpdatesDatabase` test is working by itself and fails when run as part of the test suite during build e.g. when tests are run with `mvn clean install`.

You should verify this by [running this single test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) using Maven:

```
mvn test -Dtest=ClassName.updateThingByJmsUpdatesDatabase
```

Comment: I'll update my question with findings from running a single test

Comment: Quick fix is to add `@DirtiesContext` to the test that uses `@MockBean`. Proper fix can only be provided if you show the full test context definition for both tests e.g. annotations that are applied and how the test is run. There is not enough info as of now.

Comment: All my tests already have `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`..

Comment: Added class definitions to my question

Comment: You need `AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD` as it's spilling to the next test, unless the next test is annotated with `DirtiesContext`. Please post an example to reproduce the problem, currently you only provided part of the information needed.

Comment: All my tests had dirtiescontext and before each test method. Changing it to after each test method seems to do the trick :) not sure why though, seems they should result in the same. After makes more sense to have though, let's the tests clean up after themselves.

Comment: @Tobb as a side note, `@DirtiesContext` is really a hack that increases the test suite runtime because context is not reused.

Comment: Yeah, what I really want is to start with a fresh ActiveMQ and database for each test. The beans themselves are unchanged from test to test. Do you know if there is a way to just clear external resources, but keep the spring context itself?